# Rotation, reflection and scale using SVD for complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, svd

I get that in the case of a real $n\times n$ matrix, $M$, in the SVD of $M = USV^T$, $U$ represents rotation and/or reflection in the input basis, $S$, the set of singular values denotes scaling and $V$ represents rotation and/or reflection in the output basis.

How to separate rotation and reflection in both input basis and output basis? And specifically, how does this work when the original matrix is complex?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The only difference in the complex case is that the $U,V$ are unitary rather than orthogonal.

Comment: Ok, but how to get the rotation and reflection matrices? In other words, can the $U$ and $V$ matrices be split into rotation and reflection matrices?

Comment: @user2167741: Whatever method you used when assuming the field is the Reals (looks like singular value decomposition?). Yes. (I don't even recall a need to differentiate real vs complex in proving the various decomposition results.)

Comment: Ok, even in the case of reals, how do you get these matrices?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for numerical routines? If so, you need to give more info, language, platform, etc.

Comment: I am asking for a mathematical formula for reflection and rotation matrices separately computed from $U$ and $V$. I am not sure what is not clear here.

Comment: $U,V$ are rotations.

Comment: No, $U$ and $V$ can be reflections/rotations. Please see wiki (Intuitive interpretation):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

//
In particular, if M has a positive determinant, then U and V⁎ can be chosen to be both rotations with reflections, or both rotations without reflections. If the determinant is negative, exactly one of them will have a reflection. If the determinant is zero, each can be independently chosen to be of either type.
//